# Getting list head inside for yield in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to compile following Scala code but getting compiler error `value map is not a member of ....`

```
for {
    myList: List[MyObj] = findSomeLis(List(someParam), anotherParam)
    myItem <- myList.head
  } yield activate(myItem )
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Replace `.head` with `.headOption`?
I would get rid of `for` altogether here if I were you:
`findSomeList(foo, bar).headOption.map(activate(_))`

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 2.  `=` should be `<-`.  Also without seeing implementations of `findSomeList` and the arguments being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lift the list and get the first possible entry, as in the following examples,

```
for { h <- List(1,2,3).lift(0) } yield h
Some(1)
```

namely the list is not empty; and

```
for { h <- List().lift(0) } yield h
None
```

where the list is empty. Hence

```
for { h <- findSomeLis(List(someParam), anotherParam).lift(0) } yield h
```